# Node JS: Can't Return Data and Export from Async Axios Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios

This is an incredibly simple example taken from the Axios documentation and various blog posts:

All I'm trying to do is return data from an async function and call it elsewhere:

In file: `axios.js`:

```
const axios = require("axios");

async function getJson() {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";  
  const response = await axios.get(url);
  const data = response.data;
  return data;
}

console.log(getJson());
```

Then I run `node axios.js`

But instead of logging out the actual Json data from the api as expected, its logging the Promise with:
`Promise { <pending> }`

This very simply example is taken from this post: https://scotch.io/tutorials/asynchronous-javascript-using-async-await
(Above the error handling section).

Is there something fundamental that I'm misunderstanding here? Sorry this is incredibly frustrating, I have read several blog posts and stack overflow articles, and nothing explains this or provides an answer.

For now I'm doing this one file but later the idea is simply to import and call this function in another file and get the data returned by the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to await for the async request, for example,

```
import { getJson } from '../file';
async function printJSON() {
  const jsonData = await getJson();
  console.log(jsonData);
}
```

because here getJSON is an async function.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is `async` which means it returns a `Promise`, as you've found out but clearly are not expecting.

You need to `await` the function call. E.g.

```js
console.log(await getJson());
```

Or, you could also do:

```js
getJson().then(json => {
    console.log(json);
});
```

Simple Example:

```js
const getAppointment = (appointmentId) => {
    return axios.get("example.com");
};

getAppointment(123).then(response => {

    if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log(response.data); // Do what you want with the JSON
    }

});
```

Comment: You can't do this: `console.log(await getJson());` - it says: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: Regarding the `then` example - I thought whole point of async/await is write code that looks synchronous and move away from the `then` syntax.

Comment: @daneasterman I suggest you go away and properly understand the topic, perhaps try watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QO4NXhWo_NM. He is very good at explaining the basics. Once you think you understand, then write the code.

Comment: Also: 

getJson().then(json => {
  console.log(json);
});

Prints out everything, not just the data. `json.data` doesn't help either.

Comment: @rhy_stubbs I have been doing a lot of reading and researching on promises to try to understand it before writing the code for my real example. That's also why I have gone back to this simple example, to try to go back to first principles.

Comment: Future readers note: "the await operator can only be used inside an async function", so having await outside in console.log will never work. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: @daneasterman Sorry, maybe my answer confused  you. I think what I and the other posters have tried to get accross is that you needed to `await` the fuction call. Where and when you can do this is another matter. I did not expect you to copy and paste the console.log(//...) statement directly. Rather, for you to use it as a means of seeing what a solution might look like. FYI the console.log() would work if it were within a `async` function.

Comment: @rhy_stubbs thanks for clarifying this now. All other commenters who came up with the same console.log "solution" have deleted their answers now.